# Sometimes missing textarea value when processing POST

Tags: php, post, textarea

I'm having trouble with a textarea post value not getting processed sometimes. The problem is that intermittently I'm missing some values for textarea 27 and 30. It doesn't seem to be a browser issue and it doesn't seem to be a problem with data length.

This is the form html:

```
  <div id="surveycontainer">
      <form method="POST" action="blog/questions" name="exitform">
      <input id="pnum" type="hidden" name="pagenum" value="3"/>

      <div class="qsection">
        <p> 
          27.  Suppose that a friend from another nation comes to see you and doesn’t know about the U.S. economy. How would you <span style="font-style:italic">describe the economy</span> to your friend?  Please actually write the words you would say as specifically as possible.
        </p>
        <textarea id="mlq1" name="27" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="qsection">
        <p> 
          28. What is your opinion about the future of the U.S. economy? Do you think that over the next few months the U.S. economy will improve, become worse, or stay the same?
        </p>
          <input type="radio" name="28" value="-2"><span class="radiotext">-2 (Greatly worse)</span><br/>
          <input type="radio" name="28" value="-1"><span class="radiotext">-1 (Worse)</span> <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="28"  value="0"><span class="radiotext">0 (Stay the same)</span> <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="28" value="1"><span class="radiotext">1 (Better)</span> <br/>
          <input type="radio" name="28" value="2"><span class="radiotext">2 (Much better)</span>
      </div>

      <div class="qsection">
        <p> 
          29. What are the reasons for your prediction? Explain or list them.
        </p>
        <textarea id="mlq2" name="29" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="qsection">
        <p> 
          30. What do you suggest as a solution to improve the U.S. economy?
        </p>
        <textarea id="mlq3" name="30" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>
```

And here is the processing php:

```
private function processAnswers($pid) 
  {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    $created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
      if ($key == "pagenum")
        continue;
      // echo "$key: $value \n";
      $sql = "insert into default_answers (participant_id, answer_id, answer_value, created) values (" . $pid . ",'" . htmlspecialchars($key) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($value) . "', '" . $created . "')"; 
      // echo $sql;
      $this->db->query($sql);
    }   
  }
```

This is the code that calls it:

```
if (isset($_POST['pagenum'])) {
  $pagenum = $this->input->post('pagenum');

  $this->processAnswers($pid);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What error are you seeing exactly? The database is occasionally missing values for those rows? That might indicate a problem with the input not being escaped properly.

Comment: Are you sure there's data in those `<textarea>` elements when they're posted? If not they won't appear in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: Does this only happen randomly, or can you determine how to repeat the missing input? [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) might be helpful here. I also like to debug these situations with Chrome's developer tools to see what the browser is passing even before it gets sent to the destination URL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mock Daear, that was it. mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars). It was happening when there was a single quote in the input.